# Packers Material for learn how to unpack software

Tags: packers

I would like to known where i can found guides to learn how to unpack packers like Themida, Armadillo, VMProtect, etc. I was searching challenges and guides but i could not found for packers, only other types of challenges. I have to learn how unpack that type of software, i'm new in this world of RE but i need to learn this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just starting out learn Assembly and Study C, and don't try to learn how to "unpack" commercial protectors (They are commercial for a reason), even if you want to insist on the error easily you will find scripts to do all the work for you, but I ask you, will you learn something new or just say that you know how to unpack with someone else's scripts? focus on the base, I recommend that you read **[beginners RE](https://beginners.re/main.html)**, if you want an excellent book read **Practical Reverse Engineering: X86, X64, ARM, Windows Kernel**(**ISBN: 9781118787250**), these books will teach you the necessary basics, after finishing your reading you will be able to unpack simple protections, and with a focus you will learn the tricks of commercial protectors and how to get rid of them and differentiate code virtualization, good studies.

Comment: if you want to insist on this error, here is an unpack tutorial for vmprotect, but remember what I said: https://youtu.be/aoa89Khfgr0

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was really helpful. We start with the study (it was a group research) because we understand that the most important thing it is to know the bases of RE.